# Jquery - jQuery Form Plugin and page reload

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

i try to build an autosubmit with the [Jquery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

for example

```
$("#my_form").change(function(){
  document.my_up_form.submit();    
});
```

The file upload and everything works but i get a page reload. I dont understand that.
When use the normal submit button it works (no page reload).

Can somebody tell me what the different between a normal `<input type="submit" value="go" />` and the `document.myform.submit();` is?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

**UPDATE**
Hi Lee,
thank you very much for the fast answer.

This `document.my_up_form.ajaxSubmit();` will not work but this `$('#my_up_form').ajaxSubmit();` do the job.

But know i have a new the problem .. i dont get a answer.

Whats wrong know?

```
$('#my_up_form').ajaxForm({dataType:  'json', success:   processJson});
function processJson(data)
{
  if(data['success'] == true)
  {
     alert('true');
  }
  else
  {
     alert('false');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery `ajaxForm` modifies the submit button so that it calls `ajaxSubmit()` instead of the browser's normal action.  When you call `submit()` you're invoking the browser's normal action.  you should call `ajaxSubmit()` instead.

```
$("#my_form").change(function(){
  document.my_up_form.ajaxSubmit();    
});
```

Check the ["API" tab](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) on the same documentation page you linked.